# Squares appear on monitor, computer shuts down, on reboot there are red dots

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I was playing a game, when it froze and squares appeared all over the screen. The computer shut down, and on reboot, there are lots of red dots all over the screen, the second monitor doesn't seem to be detected (it is completely black and no windows/etc can be moved to it as if there was only 1 monitor), and the resolution was set to the same as it would be in safe mode.

I tried rebooting in safe mode, but all the problems were still there. When booting up the computer, white dots can be seen on the motherboard logo screen, then on the screens where there is just white text and black background, there is no problems, then from the windows logo onwards the red dots appear.

I can change the resolution in the control panel from 800x600 to 1280x1024 (previously it could go up to 1920x1080), but the second monitor is still not detected.

Device manager says windows has stopped the graphics card driver because it has reported problems.

What is the problem/how can I determine what the problem is? How can I fix it?

Computer specs:
http://speccy.piriform.com/results/ekY4iMMemqiQ4pa1jWoYtPL

Comment: What you describe indicates the GPU has failed on your system.

Comment: I've seen the red dots issue caused by a bad video cable (specifically, HDMI).

Answer (score 1):

The squares and dots are called 'Artifacts'. You get these when the graphics hardware fails on your system for whatever reason. It could be down to a bad overheat or a bad overclock, or something else that has caused permanent damage. You will need a new graphics card. The resolution change would indicate the computer can no longer determine the exact model of the graphics card and is running on generic drivers to give very basic functionality.

Comment: What I suspected but sad to have it confirmed :( It wasn't overclocked - is there any way of telling what caused the damage?

Comment: (added as it won't let me edit) I don't think it would have overheated as I was just playing the same game that I have been for three years on this card.

Comment: How many fans do you have?

Comment: I think 6 in the case then two on the graphics card and one on the cpu.